# FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When I execute code like the one below, with pandas `isin`, I get the following warning message:

> D:\PY_PROJECT\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py:569:
>   FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar
>   instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison   mask
>   |= (ar1 == a)

This is my code :

```
import pandas as pd

path_teradata="D:/IRDATA/FULLDATA/det_usage_teradata2019/det_usage_teradata_201901.txt"
path_tapin="D:/IRDATA/FULLDATA/tapin_2019/REPORT_USAGE_TAPIN_201901.csv"

tapin=pd.read_csv(path_tapin,delimiter=',',error_bad_lines = False)
teradata=pd.read_csv(path_teradata,delimiter='|', error_bad_lines= False)

tap_msisdn=tapin.MSISDN.unique().tolist()


print teradata[teradata['msisdn'].isin(tapin['MSISDN'])]
```

How can I fix this issue?